# Как правильно подсвечивать якорные ссылки на VanillaJS?

Tags: javascript

Всем добрый вечер.
Есть меню с `position: fixed` в которой расположены ссылки.
Задача: менять цвет якоря в соответствующей секции этому якорю.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let topSectionOne = sectionOne.getBoundingClientRect().top - menuFixedHeight;
  let botSectionOne = sectionOne.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - menuFixedHeight;
  let topSectionTwo = sectionTwo.getBoundingClientRect().top - menuFixedHeight;

  if (topSectionOne <= 0) {
    sectionOneButton.classList.add('active');
  }

  if (botSectionOne <= 0 && topSectionTwo <= 0) {
    sectionOneButton.classList.remove('active');
    sectionTwoButton.classList.add('active');
  }
});
```

Такой способ не очень хороший, да и много нюансов. Подскажите, как не плодить кучу `if`'ов, а может как-то можно сделать на одном `if`'e?

Comment: как ты хочешь определять, на какой ты сейчас секции? Например если у тебя на экране видно сразу несколько

Comment: Можно ведь получить верхнюю точку секции и нижнюю, и если окно браузера ниже нижней, то отключать якорь... или я что - то не так понимаю?